# Openemr installation || database connection error

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, installation

I am trying to install openemr in linux, I have followed the instructions given in [this link](http://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/OpenEMR_4.2.2_Linux_Installation). But I am getting an error at step 3, i.e.,

> Configuring OpenEMR... Connecting to MySQL Server... ERROR. Check your
>   login credentials. unable to connect to database as root

What should I enter in the fields **Password** and **Initial User Password** in step 2. I have mysql installed in this computer, do I need to enter that password or give new password? I dont have mysql password and I tried giving new password in those fields but it didn't work. [Please check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBFxw.png) and help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You need the initial root password as configured in MySQL upon installation. Check your package documentation to find out what that is. Might be an empty password.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing it on localhost, 
by default, mysql don't has root password. So, First you need to set password for root in MySQL and then start installation.

Initial user password means, you have to give the password, which is used to access OpenEMR.